# php mollie payments recurring billing

Tags: php, payment, recurring-billing, mollie

My code is :

```
$customer = $mollie->customers->create([
    "name"    => $name,
    "email"   => $email,
]);

$customer->createSubscription([
    "amount"          => [
            "currency"    => 'USD',
            "value"       => 20.00,
    ],
    "interval"        => '2months',
    "times"           => 3,
    "description"     => $someDescription,
    "webhookUrl"      => $webhook,
    "method"          => NULL,
]);

$payment = $customer->createPayment([
    "amount" => [
            "currency"    => 'USD',
            "value"       => 20.00,
    ],
    "description"     => $someDescription,
    "redirectUrl"     => $siteUrl,
    "webhookUrl"      => $webhook,
    "metadata" => [
        "order_id" => $orderId,
    ],
    "sequenceType" => \Mollie\Api\Types\SequenceType::SEQUENCETYPE_FIRST,
]);
```

The result is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mollie\Api\Exceptions\ApiException'
>   with message 'Error executing API call (422: Unprocessable Entity): No
>   suitable mandates found for customer. Field: customerId.

Is something that I missing??

Comment: You haven't yet stored the customer ID you are creating this charge and subscription for, `$customer->id` should hold it. See #3 on the [documentation](https://docs.mollie.com/payments/recurring) for referencing the customer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the customer ID for the customer you created previously.

```
    $payment = $customer->createPayment([
        "customerId"      => $customer->id, /* see #3 in documentation */
        "amount" => [
                "currency"    => 'USD',
                "value"       => 20.00,
        ],
        "description"     => $someDescription,
        "redirectUrl"     => $siteUrl,
        "webhookUrl"      => $webhook,
        "metadata" => [
            "order_id" => $orderId,
        ],
        "sequenceType" => \Mollie\Api\Types\SequenceType::SEQUENCETYPE_FIRST,
    ]);
```

Comment: The error is trigged after $customer->createSubscription([]);

Comment: And when I put the customerId in createSubscription() I get :                        
        Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mollie\Api\Exceptions\ApiException' with message 'Error executing API call (422: Unprocessable Entity): Non-existent body parameter "customerId" for this API call. Did you mean: "times"?. Field: customerId.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer on my own question:
In order to add a subscription for an user you must first add the payment and after that the subscription.

```
        $customer = $mollie->customers->create([
            "name"    => $fullName,
            "email"   => $email,
        ]);

        $payment = $customer->createPayment([
            "amount" => [
                "currency"    => $currency,
                "value"       => $amount,
            ],
            "description"     => $description,
            "redirectUrl"     => $siteUrl,
            "webhookUrl"      => $webhook,
            "metadata" => [
                "order_id" => $orderId,
            ],
            "sequenceType" => \Mollie\Api\Types\SequenceType::SEQUENCETYPE_FIRST,
        ]);

        $customer->createSubscription([
            "amount"      => [
                "currency"    => $currency,
                "value"       => $amount,
            ],
            "times"       => $recurringLimit,
            "interval"    => $interval,
            "description" => $description,
            "webhookUrl"  => $webhook,
            "method"      => NULL,
        ]);
```

Comment: The subscription needs to be in the webhook